# Appropriate use cases for HTML's "hidden" attribute? Tabbed content?

Tags: html, dom

On [the MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/hidden) for the hidden attribute, it states (emphasis mine):

> Appropriate use cases for hidden include:
>
> - Content that **isn't yet relevant but may be needed later**
> - Content that **was previously needed but is not any longer**
> - Content that is reused by other parts of the page in a template-like fashion
> - Creating an offscreen canvas as a drawing buffer
>
> Inappropriate use cases include:
>
> - **Hiding panels in a tabbed dialog box**

This is confusing and I'm not sure what delineation they are trying to convey & why. What is tabbed content, if not content that is not yet relevant but may be needed later and then was previously needed but is not any longer?

Also, is there anything normative about this?

Comment: You hide something that you want to show later. You show something and then you want to hide it. You have made tabs, the ones that are not active have their panels/content hidden. Why is that confusing?

Comment: Right.... The thing that is confusing is that MDN says that tabbing would be an **inappropriate** use case, even though it is just a composition of things that it says **are** appropriate

Comment: Ah - ok. I assume display:none would make more sense

Answer (score 0):

Your question made me think and I reached to HTML documentation which says:

> When specified on an element, [the hidden attribute] indicates that the element is not yet, or is no longer, directly relevant to the page’s current state, or that it is being used to declare content to be reused by other parts of the page as opposed to being directly accessed by the user.

I think that it's about what we assume one element is. Modal or dialog box is treated as single element though it's not advised to add `hidden` html attribute to it. Also if page's current state is displaying tabbed dialog box (like f.e. displaying log in modal, which will be the only relevant element till logging in and completely irrelevant after) so all tabs are relevant to current page's state.

What I'm trying to say - it's purely semantical difference. If your use case of `hidden` attribute can be justified by above explanation, do it. If not, it's better to stick to CSS way.